# Handle exceptions as spring do

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to handle exceptions without override default spring handler for validation.

If i do not implement an exception handler by @ControllerAdvice, my validation erros will response like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-25T13:15:30.037+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
        {
            "codes": [
                "Null.notificationEntity.id",
                "Null.id",
                "Null.java.math.BigInteger",
                "Null"
            ],
            "arguments": [
                {
                    "codes": [
                        "notificationEntity.id",
                        "id"
                    ],
                    "arguments": null,
                    "defaultMessage": "id",
                    "code": "id"
                }
            ],
            "defaultMessage": "must be null",
            "objectName": "notificationEntity",
            "field": "id",
            "rejectedValue": 15,
            "bindingFailure": false,
            "code": "Null"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Validation failed for object='notificationEntity'. Error count: 1",
    "path": "/v1/notifications"
}
```

The repsonse above is nice and clear for me, but if i create an exception handler, to handle my own exceptions, i have to manually handle validation errors throwed by @Valid.
I have found here a sample about it: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services

But on this example i still have to implement manually, and my result is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-25T13:07:22.779+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors\nField error in object 'notificationEntity' on field 'id': rejected value [15]; codes [Null.notificationEntity.id,Null.id,Null.java.math.BigInteger,Null]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [notificationEntity.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default message [must be null]",
    "path": "/v1/notifications"
}
```

My question is, how could i implement my own exception handler without override spring validation handler or how could i call spring validation handler to keep the same response for validation exceptions?

Comment: Hi @feeling unwelcome i research again and did not find the duplicated. Could you paste the link here please?

Answer (score 0):

If you go with catching the exception in your `ControllerAdvice`, you will have access to the validation exception (which I assume is the one with the structure you want to replicate).

```
@ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<YourCustomResponse> handleValidationexception(ValidationException e) {
    // probably do some logging
    YourCustomResponse response = buildCustomResponse(e); // build the response payload however you see fit
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

In this way, you can set the body, the HTTP headers and the HTTP status that is returned to the client in case of a `ValidationException`.

Comment: In that link i posted, they are saying to override the method handleMethodArgumentNotValid. Its is working and i can create my custom response. But i would like to use spring handler to keep responding with the same way instead of implement my own.